# WIN 7 resource monitor: In network section, port number not available as a column?

Tags: windows-7, port, resource-monitor

On my windows 8 laptop, when I go to resource monitor, I can select port number to add to the selected columns in the display.

For some reason, on my win 7 desktop, port number is not listed in the available columns. I really need a (friendly) way to see which port numbers are in use?

Thanks v much.
[available columns in resource monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJB3Z.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I really need a (friendly) way to see which port numbers are in use?

- Click on the "Network" tab
- Click to expand the "TCP Connections" and "Listening Ports" sections to see what ports are in use:

[image]

Comment: Oh my God... I wasn't on the "network" tab AT ALL. I was staring at the "overview" tab, which (confusingly) also has a section called 'network'. Thanks a lot!! :D